# Updating an element in an ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

what's the best approach to updating an element in the content property of an ArrayController so that any associated views are updated.

Currently, i use the following piece of code, which updates the content but not the view

```
    updateContent: function(device) {
        for (var index = 0; index < this.content.length; index++) {
            if (this.content[index]._id === device._id) {
                this.content.splice(index, 1, device);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

What's the best approach for doing this?

In this particular case I am receiving calls from the server, using soket.io, as the state of devices change on updating the view accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The method name you search is [replace](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayProxy.html#method_replace) (found in MutableArray, which ArrayProxy inherits from).
Note the API differs in that you pass an array of elements to insert, e.g.

this.content.splice(index, 1, **[** device **]**);

As @ebryn stated, the Array's splice is not overridden, and the original method does change the array's content, but do not notify the observers, where the view (DOM changes handled by handlebars) is probably one of them.

I've checked this in version 0.96.

Comment: This is still relevant in Ember 1.0+: [Ember.MutableArray.replace](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_replace) is the Observer-compatible equivalent of JavaScript's Array.splice. As @shex noted, the method signature is slightly different: it accepts an Array of elements to be inserted, rather than accepting a variable length list of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using observable array methods on the content array, which is why the view isn't being updated.

See the Ember.Array/Ember.Enumerable docs for a list of observable array methods:

http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.Array&src=false

http://docs.emberjs.com/#doc=Ember.Enumerable&src=false